# Android Overlay Image On Top Of Background Image Using XML Selector

Tags: android, android-view, android-xml, android-image, android-selector

Basically what the title says:
I have a View that I have set the background image for (via the android:background attribute in XML), and I'd like to overlay another image when the user presses on the view
I know that you can use XML selectors to CHANGE the background image when the view is pressed, but is it possible to overlay an image instead?
Or will I just have to have 2 images - the plain one and then the one with the overlay added?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I presume this can be acheved with LayerDrawable: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html but as I hadn't worked with it I cannot provide you some more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Chaosit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320299/chaosit), I came up with this solution:
In res/xml you create a selector file, e.g. selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_with_overlay" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image" />
</selector>
```

In res/drawable, you then create a layer-list, e.g. image_with_overlay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/overlay_image" />
</layer-list>
```

Then in the `View` that you want to have this property, you simply use `android:background="@xml/selector"`

Then you're all done :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
// xml 
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ijoomer_btn_hover"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

//  Activity 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView("xml");
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setImageDrawable(null);
}

   img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(img.getDrawable()!=null){
                img.setImageDrawable(null);
            }else{
                img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an ImageView for the background image and set the android:tint property to be the color with an alpha filter.

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:tint="#8c000000"
    android:src="mipmap/background.png"/>
```